# SELECT instead of TABLE and WHERE in UPDATE?

Tags: sql, select, sql-update, mariadb

I've seen may answers to the same kind of question but I still doubt.

UPDATE in SQL should be something like :

```
UPDATE *Table*
SET *choose value*
WHERE *what do we change*
```

I would like to know if there is possibilites to use a select instead of TABLE (an so instead of WHERE)
Like

```
UPDATE *Select conditions and rows*
SET *What do we change (the where is implicit)
```

I know UPDATE/SET/WHERE works well, but I'm exploring other possibilites :)

Thanks,

Nicolas

*EXAMPLE :*

**Have to do :**

```
update produits
set `NO_FOURNISSEUR` = "30"
where `NO_FOURNISSEUR` = "3"
```

**would like to try something like :**

```
update select * from produits where produits.`no_fournisseur`= "30"
set `NO_FOURNISSEUR`= "3"
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  However, I would advise you to get comfortable with the standard syntax.  It is the standard syntax, after all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The ANSI SQL standard way to do this is using a Common Table Expression:

```
with dt as
(
  select * 
  from produits 
  where produits.no_fournisseur= '30'
) 
update dt set NO_FOURNISSEUR = '3'
```

This standard syntax supports joins and other query constructs in the SELECT part, and gives you a simple way to examine the rows before applying the update.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer, that's what I was expecting but it's not working. And there you are ot updating produits bur updating a new table called "dt" ? 

Error code : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'dt as
(
  select * 
  from produits 
  where produits.`no_fournisseur`= "30"' at line 1

Comment: I have no idea whether this syntax is supported by MariaDB.  SQL Server supports this.

Comment: That's **not** "standard SQL" as defined in the ANSI SQL standard. It's specific to SQL Server's T-SQL dialect. Using double quotes for string literals is also non standard SQL.

Comment: MySql supports it https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html  And SQL Server's non-standard UPDATE is its UPDATE ... FROM syntax.

Comment: Need 10.2 to get `WITH`.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB has a with expression, like so:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/with/

so you would have:

```
   WITH t AS (
   select * 
  from produits 
  where produits.no_fournisseur= '30') 
UPDATE t SET t.no_fournisseur = '3';
```